# AFNetworking and ways to map the objects

Tags: ios, rest, nsdictionary, afnetworking-2

I have a question about AFNetworking objects mapping.

I need to use AFNetworking for JSON Rest API. I haven't experience with it, I used RestKit.

My question is: AFNetworking produces always NSDictionary as response type? In this way, I can make the mapping from NSDictionary response to my properties objects...but, are there other better ways for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at [Overcoat](https://github.com/gonzalezreal/Overcoat). It couples [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) with `AFNetworking` to do the Response serialization.